# How to enable graph + search + analytics on the same server

Tags: datastax-enterprise

It seems by the documentation that it should be enough to set /etc/defaults/dse to enable all the above.
Meaning, that SPARK support was also added. 
Also the node tool now indicates that everything is up and running, and that the (single node) cluster is of type Graph, Search, Analytics
So enabling works fine, but trying to use analytics leads to exceptions in the provision level, something which probably has to do with spark configuration. But nothing is documented there.
It seems like others are stuck with this issue, too.

This is the full exception :
Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 1) Error injecting constructor, com.datastax.bdp.gcore.datastore.DataStoreException: Failed to execute statementb5807f0d-b1b0-4bc3-bd77-794d21725fbb at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl.(DseGraphImpl.java:189) at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphFactoryImpl$$Lambda$1430/208354649 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule) while locating com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl 1 error
Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - Unable to create an OLAP Traversal Source when Spark is not running or cannot be detected.

Note that this exception is received when trying to use the graph-analytics querying from studio or gremlin console.
There are no specific errors in cassandra log-files, etc.
Moreover from the point of view of the dse service, everything is seems right, but the fact that it doesn't actually work.

These are the errors that appeared after playing with some constants :

```
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:36,640 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:36,643 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:36,643 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
WARN  [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:36,671 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:36,672 SPARK-WORKER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-WORKER caused an exception in state STARTING:
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:41,644 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:41,645 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:41,647 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:41,647 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,648 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,649 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,652 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,652 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
WARN  [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,673 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:46,673 SPARK-WORKER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-WORKER caused an exception in state STARTING:
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:51,653 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:51,653 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:51,656 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:51,656 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,657 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,658 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,660 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,660 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
WARN  [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,673 SPARK-WORKER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-WORKER] 2018-07-08 18:25:56,674 SPARK-WORKER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-WORKER caused an exception in state STARTING:
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:26:01,661 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
WARN  [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:26:01,662 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:47 - Not overriding system property java.library.path
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:26:01,665 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:91 - Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:26:01,665 SPARK-MASTER Logging.scala:72 - Failed to stop redirecting UI
ERROR [SPARK-MASTER] 2018-07-08 18:26:06,665 SPARK-MASTER InternalServiceRunner.java:45 - SPARK-MASTER caused an exception in state NOT_STARTED:
```

Comment: Please post the Exception, etc. - check the `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`. Without this information it's hard to answer to your question

Comment: The problem is that there is no exception relevant to the situation under /var/log/cassandra. The issues are happening when you try to use the analytics from the studio, or via gremlin. And then you get the following Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - com.google.inject.ProvisionException: BTW, this was already posted several time, and didn't got much attention for some reason.

Comment: You mentioned exception - please add it here...

Comment: I've added the exception both to the post itself, and also to the comment

Comment: So, the Analytics component doesn't run in your cluster. Just to check - you enabled everything in the `/etc/defaults/dse` & did `service dse restart` ?

Comment: Of course I did that, I just wrote it above. And again, I'm not the only one who met those issues. Something else is wrong (not to say I would have expected some more relevant error). When you look for similar errors you see more unanswered issues like that. The problem is I've not clue what to do with it.

Comment: Can you do `egrep "ERROR|WARN" /var/log/cassandra/system.log` and put output to pastebin or gist.github.com?

Comment: This is what appeared after playing with some constants :

Comment: I've added to the main post, although those appeared after I was messing around with some constants of the yaml files.

Comment: I recommend to join DataStax Academy's Slack & ask at `#dse-graph` channel...

Comment: I think that what you are talking about is only for paying customers, and I'm just checking this for now. The DataStack's site is sending everyone to stack overflow with the tags mentioned here.

Comment: For paying customers there is support, but overall, on Slack channel other customers may help, in addition of some people from DataStax

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with this log it's becoming clearer.  The real culprit is this message: `Failed to bind MasterRedirectingUI` - this means that Spark Master can't start because somebody is already listening on port that it's trying to use - by default it's `7080`, but it's could be overwritten by setting the `SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT` variable in the file `spark-env.sh` (either in `resources/spark/conf` in tarball installation, or in `/etc/dse/spark/`).

Check that no other processes are listening on these ports - you can use `netstat -plnt` to do this...

Comment: It's not the answer. I thought the problem was that the Spark processes IPs were defined to be localhost, so I changed them to the "real" IP, and this caused the problem. Now I changed it back, and the same error, with no errors the output.log or system.log.

Comment: I mentioned, that this was not the issue.

Comment: Then I can't say  without much additional information about setup - versions, what installation type, etc.

Comment: I already gave all the setup information (not that the way should matter), as the setup was not made to be that complex - the setup was done by installing from rpm, as we are talking about Centos 7 machine. The installation was made for the last version which is 6.0.1, following the documentation from the site directly. I will say again, that unless one would like to make some custom settings, which seems terribly hard and unexplained, the installation is by following only a few steps.